# Accessing bound function as this?

Tags: javascript

So I'm writing a FFI for a JavaScript VM, and I have this situation:

```js
let myFunction = Function('console.log(this.toPrint);');
myFunction = myFunction.bind(myFunction);
//any amount of time in the future
myFunction.toPrint = "some value";
//further in the future
myFunction();
//prints undefined but ideally would print "some value" because the bound function is not the function.
```

Now, I can pass that bound function as an argument, however I have no control over the function calls themselves due to that nature of what I am creating.

While I can not use `bind`, and instead use arguments.callee inside the function, I understand that this is not good practice and may be deprecated. Is there any other alternative to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the function being created with `Function` *return* the actual function you want instead, and call the result immediately:

```js
let myFunction = Function('return function f() { console.log(f.toPrint); };')();
//any amount of time in the future
myFunction.toPrint = "some value";
//further in the future
myFunction();
//prints "some value"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use scope to save the value instead of `this`.  For example:

```js
function factory() {
  const params = {}
  
  return {
    setParam: (key, val) => {
      params[key] = val
    },
    printParam: (key) => {
      console.log(params[key])
    },
  }
}

const x = factory()
x.setParam('blah', 'something')
x.printParam('blah')
```